# Joda-Time DateTimeFormatter: get the correct output

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to convert a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) into a String, in the following format:

> Sat, 1 Jan 2011 00:00:00

I'm using this code:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
f.withLocale(Locale.US);
System.out.println(DateTime.now().toString(f));
```

My output is however:

> wo, 20 jun. 2012 00:03:31

So the problems are:

- The output is in Dutch instead of English ('wo' for 'wed')
- The month has a period

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Should preface the title of this question with "***Joda** DateTimeFormatter ...*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DateTimeFormatter.withLocale](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) returns a new DateTimeFormatter. So you need to do this:

```
f = f.withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Alternatively (equivalently):

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Doh, always something that simple.. Thanks! That immediately removes the period aswell :)